# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem. I use phpmailer smtp gmail it works on localhost but when I upload that it is showing me these errors

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

SMTP connect() failed.

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Any solution please. I am using phpmailer first time so I have no idea about it, thanks

Comment: Maybe your server is blocking access to smtp ports.

Answer (score 1):

The network that your server is running on may be blocking outgoing connections on the port that you are using to connect to smtp.gmail.com.  You can test is this is happening, by using telnet to connect from the server to smtp.gmail.com on whichever port you are trying to connect on.

Answer (score 0):

it looks as if your server is blocking access/connections to SMTP ports.